# Sending HTTP Post Request to site with array in Body

Tags: php, apify

I'm trying to make a POST request and send some values in the body of an API call. In the [documentation of the API](https://www.apify.com/docs/api/v1#/reference/executions/start-execution/start-execution) it says I need to make a POST request, using `startUrls` as an array with `key` and `value`.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://api.apify.com/v1/USERID/crawlers/CRAWLERID/execute?token=TOKENID';

$postData = array(
'startUrls' => array(array('key'=>'START', 'value'=>'https://instagram.com/instagram'))
);
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/json',
        'body' => json_encode($postData)
        )
));
$resp = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $context);
print_r($resp); 
?>
```

The JSON seems to be how it should, but the script is not sending the body properly to the website.

Comment: Why do you say that the body is not properly sent?  Do you have access to the server's logs?  What is the value of $resp?

Comment: 1. Because it doesn't start the crawler on Apify with changed URL. 

2. No, we just know it doesn't start it right, but if done with POST from console, it works. 

3. https://justpaste.it/1jabp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php), there is no `body` option for the HTTP context. Try `content` instead:

```
<?php
$url = "https://api.apify.com/v1/USERID/crawlers/CRAWLERID/execute?token=TOKENID";

$postData = [
    "startUrls" => [
        ["key"=>"START", "value" => "https://instagram.com/instagram"]
    ]
];

$context = stream_context_create([
    "http" => [
        "method"  => "POST",
        "header"  => "Content-type: application/json",
        "content" => json_encode($postData)
    ]
]);
$resp = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $context);
print_r($resp);
```

Comment: Glad to help out

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work. I have set the headers and specified the content type.

```
$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('$url = 'https://api.apify.com/v1/USERID/crawlers/CRAWLERID/execute?token=TOKENID');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
  'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));

$request->setContentType('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$request->setPostFields(array('key'=>'START', 'value'=>'https://instagram.com/instagram')
));

try {
  $response = $request->send();

  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
```

If you want to try with cUrl the following code snippet will work.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$postData = array(
'startUrls' => array(array('key'=>'START', 'value'=>'https://instagram.com/instagram'))
);

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.apify.com/v1/USERID/crawlers/CRAWLERID/execute?token=TOKENID",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                    "content-type: multipart/form-data;"
                ),
            ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
```